# MongoDB: How to aggregate and $group then filter specific date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Employee Schema**

```
const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
          throw new Error('Email is invalid');
        }
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      minLength: 6,
      validate(value) {
        if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
          throw new Error("Password can not contain a word 'password'.");
        }
      },
    },
    birthdate: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    cellphone: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    gender: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['남성', '여성'],
      required: true,
    },
    hourly_wage: {
      type: Number,
      trim: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    timeClocks: [
      {
        type: new mongoose.Schema({
          start_time: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
          },
          end_time: {
            type: Date,
          },
          wage: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
          },
          total: {
            type: Number,
          },
          totalWorkTime: {
            type: Number
          }
        }),
      },
    ],
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['staff'],
      default: 'staff',
    },
    stores: [
      {
        location: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'Location',
        },
      },
    ],
    status: {
      //현재 재직상태
      type: String,
      enum: ['재직자', '퇴직자'],
      default: '재직자',
    },
    tokens: [
      {
        token: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

**What I have done so far**

```
const employees = shifts.map((d) => d.owner._id);

    //timeclock
    const temp = await Employee.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: { $in: employees },
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: { 'timeClocks.start_time': 1 },
      },
      {
        $unwind: { path: '$timeClocks', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$_id',
          name: { $first: '$name' },
          timeClock: {
            $push: '$timeClocks',
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

**My result**

```
{
    "shifts": [
        {
            "_id": "60e05b188be53900280bcdf2",
            "date": "2021-07-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "day": "Fri",
            "start": "2021-07-09T09:41:00.000Z",
            "end": "2021-07-09T21:42:00.000Z",
            "owner": {
                "_id": "60cd9a3cb4ddcc00285b0df9",
                "name": "Dr. dd"
            },
            "location": "60cd99b1b4ddcc00285b0df3",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "timeClock": [
        {
            "_id": "60cd9a3cb4ddcc00285b0df9",
            "name": "Dr. dd",
            "timeClock": [
                {
                    "_id": "60def63d19648a00286f0539",
                    "start_time": "2021-05-04T02:19:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2021-05-04T14:42:00.000Z",
                    "wage": 8720,
                    "total": 107735,
                    "totalWorkTime": 743
                },
                {
                    "_id": "60def63f19648a00286f053d",
                    "start_time": "2021-05-02T08:12:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2021-05-02T22:24:00.000Z",
                    "wage": 8720,
                    "total": 123540,
                    "totalWorkTime": 852
                },
                {
                    "_id": "60def64119648a00286f0541",
                    "start_time": "2021-05-10T20:14:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2021-05-10T22:17:00.000Z",
                    "wage": 8720,
                    "total": 17835,
                    "totalWorkTime": 123
                },
        }
   ]
```

**Expected Result(2021-05-10)**

```
{
    "shifts": [
        {
            "_id": "60e05b188be53900280bcdf2",
            "date": "2021-07-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "day": "Fri",
            "start": "2021-07-09T09:41:00.000Z",
            "end": "2021-07-09T21:42:00.000Z",
            "owner": {
                "_id": "60cd9a3cb4ddcc00285b0df9",
                "name": "Dr. dd"
            },
            "location": "60cd99b1b4ddcc00285b0df3",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "timeClock": [
        {
            "_id": "60cd9a3cb4ddcc00285b0df9",
            "name": "Dr. dd",
            "timeClock": {
                    "_id": "60def64119648a00286f0541",
                    "start_time": "2021-05-10T20:14:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2021-05-10T22:17:00.000Z",
                    "wage": 8720,
                    "total": 17835,
                    "totalWorkTime": 123
                },
        }
    ]
```

I am receiving the 'date string' example('URL/2021-05-10') via params and trying to query all employees that have the same date timeClocks.
also trying to send back everything I queried without different dates from timeClocks.
How can I filter out non-same dates?

Answer (score 0):

You have string `2021-05-10` now you need a `$match` stage before your group so you can filter out `timeClock`. Something like:

```
{ $match: { 'timeClocks.start_time': new Date('2021-05-10') } }
```

Modify the match stage to your requirements like maybe add `$gte` or `$lte` or something like that.